# A form submit returns {"error": "'action'"}

Tags: django, ajax, form-submit, production

I have a form submit that crashes in production with the following error **{"error": "'action'"}**, but for some weird reason does not happen in local way. The input with id="btnEditar" is the one that push the error. The error is displayed in a white page.

Nothing appears in the console of the browser and as far as the error doesnt ocurr in local no messages appears in the backend.

I have tried to reload js in several browsers but with the same results... running on Django local dev server the form is submitted OK and the data is updated as well, but in pythonanywhere prod server the error mentionated error comes up. hope you can help me to figure it out!!

Here is the template code:

```
      {% extends 'core/home.html' %}
      {% load static %}
      {% load bootstrap %}
      <!doctype html>
      <html lang="es">
      <head>
      </head>
      <body class="text-center">
          {% block content %}
          <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="HiddenId">{{ object.id }}</div>
          <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="HiddenFecAnt">{{ object.start_time }}</div>
          <div class="container mb-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="card w-24" style="height: 7rem; width: 14rem; margin: 2px">
                <div class="card-header" style="height: 2.5rem;" >
                  Fecha de Reprogramación
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        {{form.start_time|bootstrap}}
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                <!--lista de turnos del dia-->
                <div class="card w-24" style="height: 7rem; width: 27rem; margin: 2px">
                  <div class="card-header" style="height: 2.5rem;" >
                    Paciente
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="txtNombrePac">{{ object.paciente }}</div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="visibility: hidden">
                      {{form.paciente|bootstrap}}
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card w-24" style="height: 7rem; width: 18rem; margin: 2px">
                  <div class="card-header" style="height: 2.5rem;" >
                    Telefono
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      {{form.telefono|bootstrap}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card w-24" style="height: 7rem; width: 10rem;margin: 2px">
                  <div class="card-header" style="height: 2.5rem;">
                    Accion
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <input style="height: 2rem; margin-top: 1px;" type="submit" id="btnEditar" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Editar Turno" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <p></p>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="card w-24" style="height: 50rem; width: 70rem; margin: 2px">
                <div class="card-header" style="height: 2.5rem;" >
                  Turnos del Dia
                </div>
                <!--Slots de los turnos del dia-->
                <div class="card-body">
                      <section class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="card-columns">
                                <div id=14:00 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">14:00</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p14:00 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o14:00 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=14:30 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">14:30</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p14:30 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o14:30 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=15:00 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">15:00</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p15:00 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o15:00 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=15:30 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">15:30</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p15:30 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o15:30 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=16:00 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">16:00</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p16:00 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o16:00 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=16:30 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">16:30</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p16:30 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o16:30 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div id=17:00 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">17:00</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p17:00 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o17:00 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=17:30 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(182, 197, 157);">17:30</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p17:30 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o17:30 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=18:00 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 214, 168);">18:00</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p18:00 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o18:00 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=18:15 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 214, 168)">18:15</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p18:15 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o18:15 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=18:30 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 214, 168)">18:30</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <p id=p18:30 class="card-text" ></p>
                                    <p id=o18:30 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=18:45 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 214, 168)">18:45</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p18:45 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o18:45 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=19:00 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 168, 168)">19:00</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p19:00 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o19:00 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=19:15 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header"  style="background-color: rgb(219, 168, 168)">19:15</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p19:15 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o19:15 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=19:30 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 168, 168)">19:30</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p19:30 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o19:30 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id=19:45 class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 10.5rem;">
                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgb(219, 168, 168)">19:45</div>
                                  <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id=p19:45 class="card-title" ></h5>
                                    <p id=o19:45 class="card-text"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </section> 
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        {% endblock %}
      </body>
```

And this is the js looks like:

```
$("#btnEditar").click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault(e);
    //
    //Validaciones
    fectur=document.getElementById("fecha").value;   
    if (fectur.length<1){
            alert("Debe Seleccionar una Fecha Valida.");  
        return false; 
        }
    tele=document.getElementById("id_telefono").value;   
        if (tele.length<1){
            alert("Debe Ingresar un Telefono.");  
        return false; 
        }
    resuldia=esdialaborale(fectur);
    console.log("este es el resultado de la funcion : " + resuldia)
    if (resuldia!=1){
            alert("Debe Seleccionar un Lunes, Martes o Miercoles.");  
        return false; 
        }
    elementos=document.getElementsByClassName("card border-primary mb-3");//Si ya hay un slot seleccionado ->sale
    console.log(" cantidad de slots marcados:" + elementos.length)
    if (elementos.length ===0){
        alert("Debe seleccionar una hora para el turno.")
        return false;
    }
    if(elementos.length>1){
        alert("Dos horas han sido seleccionadas. Vuelva a seleccionar la hora del turno.")
        do{
            for (x=0;x<elementos.length;x++) {
                document.getElementById(elementos[x].id).className="card bg-light mb-3";
            }
        }
        while (elementos.length>0)    
        return false;
    }
    if (user!='Silvia'){
        if (user!=''){
            if (document.getElementById(elementos[0].id).id==='19:00'){
                alert("Los turnos de las 19 horas son gestionado por la Dra. Ulloa.")
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById(elementos[0].id.id)==='19:15'){
                alert("Los turnos de las 19 horas son gestionado por la Dra. Ulloa.")
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById(elementos[0].id).id==='19:30'){
                alert("Los turnos de las 19 horas son gestionado por la Dra. Ulloa.")
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById(elementos[0].id).id==='19:45'){
                alert("Los turnos de las 19 horas son gestionado por la Dra. Ulloa.")
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Confirma Editar
    if (confirm('Esta seguro que Desea Editar el Turno?')) {
        // Edit it!
            //Encabezado
            var codigos=[];
            var pac = document.getElementById("id_paciente").value;
            codigos.push(pac);
            var tel =  document.getElementById("id_telefono").value;
            if (document.getElementById("id_telefono").value.length==0){dir=""}
            codigos.push(tel);
            var fec =  document.getElementById("fecha").value;
            codigos.push(fec);
            codigos.push(hor);
            var idt =  document.getElementById("HiddenId").innerHTML;
            codigos.push(idt);//Id turno a editar
            var fecant= document.getElementById("HiddenFecAnt").innerHTML;
            codigos.push(fecant);//Fecha turno original antes de editar
            var token = '{{csrf_token}}';  
            //var data = JSON.stringify({"codigos":codigos});
            data = {"codigos[]":codigos,"action":'reschedule'};
            console.log(data);  
            $.ajax({  
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },  
                //"url": '/turnos/edit/'+idt+'/',
                "url": '/turnos/edit/',
                "type": "POST",  
                "dataType": "json",
                data: data,  
                success: function(data){
                    if(data['success']){
                        //Manda a Imprimrir pdf
                        if (confirm('¿Desea Imprimir el Turno?')) {
                            window.open("/turnos/pdf/"+idt+"/", '_blank');
                            window.location="/turnos/list/"
                        }else{
                            window.location="/turnos/list/"
                        }
                        //alert("El turno se registro correctamente.");
                        ("/turnos/pdf/"+proxid+"/", '_blank');
                        window.location="/turnos/list/"
                        //location.reload(true);
                    }
                },  
                error: function(a,b,c){  
                alert(c); 
                } 
            });
    } else {
        // Do nothing!
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is the view:

```
class TurnosEditView(UpdateView):
    model=Turnos
    form_class=TurnosEditForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('turnos:list')
    template_name="turnos/turnos_edit.html"

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
    
    def sumar_hora(self,hora1,hora2):
        formato = "%H:%M:%S"
        lista = hora2.split(":")
        hora=int(lista[0])
        minuto=int(lista[1])
        segundo=int(lista[2])
        h1 = datetime.strptime(hora1, formato)
        dh = timedelta(hours=hora) 
        dm = timedelta(minutes=minuto)          
        ds = timedelta(seconds=segundo) 
        resultado1 =h1 + ds
        resultado2 = resultado1 + dm
        resultado = resultado2 + dh
        resultado=resultado.strftime(formato)
        return str(resultado)

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data={}
        try:
            action=request.POST['action']
            if action == 'reschedule': #TurnoEdit
                print("adentro de Edit")
                codigos=request.POST.getlist("codigos[]")#Codigo/s de los turnos
                fecha=codigos[2]
                hora=codigos[3]
                fecha=fecha+ " " + hora
                fechaforma=datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                #hora fin
                hora1=hora+":00"
                if hora1[0:2]== '14':
                    horafin= self.sumar_hora(hora1,"00:30:00")
                elif hora1[0:2]== '15':
                    horafin= self.sumar_hora(hora1,"00:30:00")
                elif hora1[0:2]== '16':
                    horafin= self.sumar_hora(hora1,"00:30:00")
                elif hora1[0:2]== '17':
                    horafin= self.sumar_hora(hora1,"00:30:00")
                else:
                    horafin= self.sumar_hora(hora1,"00:15:00")
                fecha=codigos[2]+ " " + horafin
                fechaformafin=datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                idte=codigos[4]
                #Edicion
                tu= Turnos.objects.get(pk=int(idte))
                usuario=tu.user
                tu.user=usuario
                paciente=tu.paciente
                tu.paciente=paciente
                tu.telefono=codigos[1]
                tu.start_time=fechaforma
                tu.end_time=fechaformafin
                ahora=datetime.now()
                date_time_ahora = ahora.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                #fecha orgiinal turno
                fecori=codigos[5]
                if tu.observaciones=="":
                    print("Es igual a comillascomillas")
                    tu.observaciones= "(R)" + date_time_ahora + "_" + str(self.request.user) + "- Original: " + fecori
                else:
                    print("Ya tiene algo escrito")
                    tu.observaciones= tu.observaciones + ". (R)" + date_time_ahora + "_" + str(self.request.user) + "- Original: " + fecori
                print(tu.observaciones)
                tu.save()
                data['success']=True
            elif action == 'getuser':
                data=[]
                print(self.request.user.username)
                data.append(self.request.user.username)
                print(data)
            else:
                data['error']='No ha ingresado ningún dato'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

And Finally the url:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views  import TurnosListView,TurnosCreateView,TurnosInvoicePdfView,TurnosEditView,TurnosRePrintListView

turnos_patterns = ([
    path('list/', TurnosListView.as_view(), name="list"),
    path('reprint/', TurnosRePrintListView.as_view(), name="reprint"),
    path('create/',TurnosCreateView.as_view(),name="create"),
    path('edit/<slug:pk>/',TurnosEditView.as_view(),name="edit"),
    path('pdf/<int:pk>/',TurnosInvoicePdfView.as_view(),name='pdf')
    ], 'turnos')
```

OH the last one, here is the form class code:

```
class TurnosEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Turnos
        fields =  '__all__'
        widgets = {
        'start_time': forms.DateInput(format='%Y-%m-%d',attrs={'id':"fecha",'class':"form-control",'style':"height: 2rem; margin-top: -25px; text-align:right;",'type':'date','value':datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}),
        'paciente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','style':"height: 2rem; margin-top: -25px;", 'placeholder':''}),
        'telefono': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','style':"height: 2rem; margin-top: -25px;", 'placeholder':'Ingrese un Telefono'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'start_time':'', 'telefono':'','paciente':'',
        }
```

Comment: Hi there, I have an update to share. Issue is related to AJAX call, so here i am debugging but still did not catch the bug. Hope i can share the fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.... I was working with non updated static files since I have never run collectstatic in production server :S

Now its working the same way as development environment. :)

Regards,